# When are all signatures represented by units?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

What conditions on a number field imply that every signature is represented by a unit? Are there conditions that imply that it is not the case that every signature is represented by a unit?

For example, if K is a cubic cyclic number field with odd class number then all signatures are represented by units by Theorem V in [Armitage, J., & Fröhlich, A. (1967). Classnumbers and unit signatures. Mathematika, 14(1), 94-98. doi:10.1112/S0025579300008044].

What are some references for articles on this topic?

Answer (score 4):

The structure of the group of units modulo totally positive units is studied [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5674.pdf); see also the references in this article. Since then, relevant articles by [Dummit](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.05535.pdf) and [Dummit & Voight](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/articles/Dummit_Voight__2-Selmer_Group_and_Signatures_of_Units__PLMS_accepted_5_19_2018.pdf) have appeared.